# How can I run MongoDB "adminCommand" in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I need to get the list of `MongoDB` databases in `Mule`.

Here is the Mongo CLI command - `db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )`

I tried below way and that doesn't worked

> < mongo:execute-command config-ref="Mongo_DB" commandName="eval"
>   commandValue="db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )" doc:name="Mongo
>   DB" />

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Mongo specifics, however the connector needs a JSON document as the command which you can use Dataweave to build. Something like:

```
<mongo:execute-generic-command config-ref="Mongo_DB">
            <mongo:command ><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{   
  listDatabases: 1
}]]]></mongo:command>
        </mongo:execute-generic-command>
```